# how to get value of depth image from *.bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone~
I have created *.bag file with rosbag, but how can I extract the value of each pixel in the depth image from the *.bag file? My goal is to create a .txt for each depth image in *.bag, describing pixel value in depth image.
Would u please tell me how to do that?
Thanks very much!
Bo Yu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87981/how-to-get-value-of-depth-image-from-*.bag-file/) by [YUBO.ZUZU](https://answers.ros.org/users/7346/yubo.zuzu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A great place to start is: [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/10489/recording-video-from-the-pr2/)

If the [tutorial linked there](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data) is insufficient for your needs, the [bag_to_video code linked to there](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/opencv_additions.git) should give you the appropriate template for creating a tool to suit you.

**Edit**

Actually more informative [code can be found here](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/rosbag_video/html/bag__to__video_8cpp_source.html). See in particular the lines opening the bag and looping over its messages:

```
00068         // Load input bag file
00069         rosbag::Bag bag;
00070     bag.open(bag_in_name, rosbag::bagmode::Read);
00071         ROS_INFO("Opened %s", bag_in_name.c_str());
00072 
00073         // Create output bag file
00074         rosbag::Bag bag_out;
00075     bag_out.open(bag_out_name, rosbag::bagmode::Write);
00076         ROS_INFO("Created %s", bag_out_name.c_str());
00077 
00078         // Get topics
00079     rosbag::View view(bag);
00080 
00081         // Loop over messages
00082         BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view) {
00083 
00084                 // Get data
00085         sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr image_msg = m.instantiate<sensor_msgs::Image>();
```

The part converting this to an OpenCV image:

```
00091         if (image_msg != NULL) {
00092 
00093             cv::Mat image;
00094 
00095             if (image_msg->encoding == "32FC1") { // depth image
00096                 cv_bridge::CvImagePtr depth_image_ptr;
00097                 try {
00098                     depth_image_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_msg);
00099                 } catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
00100                     ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
00101                 }
```

And the part reading the pixels off this image:

```
    00105                 for(int y = 0; y < depth_image_ptr->image.rows; y++) {
    00106                     for(int x = 0; x < depth_image_ptr->image.cols; x++) {
    00107                         float distance = depth_image_ptr->image.at<float>(y, x);
```

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YUBO.ZUZU](https://answers.ros.org/users/7346/yubo.zuzu/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thanks very much, but my goal is to extract the distance value of each pixel in the depth image, rather than generate video. How can I do that? Can you tell me?